# Setup error codes on IIS 6.0

Tags: http, iis

I want the IIS server to return `HTTP 304 (Not Modified)` when a particular file is accessed.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Enable Content Expiration" box on the HTTP Headers tab in IIS Manager:

[IIS 6.0 F1: Web Site Properties - HTTP Headers Tab](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732442.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it isn't possible to do this (in IIS).  There are a few criteria that have to be met for this code to be sent out:

1. Client must have cached copy of page.
2. The request's **If-Modified-Since** HTTP Header Time/date stamp must match what's on the server.

If both of those conditions are true, the server will return a HTTP 304 status code.

Comment: How would you check to see if this feature is activated? Does it need to be activated, or is it just ON by default?